# Nexus REST API query artifacts within a group

Tags: rest, nexus

I have a Nexus maven repo and I would like to leverage REST API to query the list of artifacts lying in my specific group. I stumbled upon this documentation but it seems to be very concise  and I cannot find there what I need.

https://oss.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/rest.html

I want something like this

```
http://mydomain:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/list?groupId=com.test.superproduct&repo=snapshots
```

And it would output me a list

- product-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- product-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
- product-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
  .....

To be more specific I need a list of versions of artifacts lying in a group, but I can extract versions from artifact names too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It came out that everything I needed is to fetch ˇmaven-metadata.xml` file that comprises all versions available for this artifact. For example,

```
https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/com/alibaba/rocketmq/rocketmq-all/maven-metadata.xml
```

contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.alibaba.rocketmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>rocketmq-all</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>3.1.8-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release></release>
    <versions>
      <version>3.0.2-open-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>3.0.10-ALIYUN-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>3.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>3.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20140807060304</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Comment: how did u fetch the xml file?

Comment: ajc, what do you mean? It depends on the language/technology you are using, but in all cases it's just a matter of doing a regular http request and handling a response. I just loaded it with my Gradle script and extracted the data with built in XML parser.

Answer (score 17):

No need to manually parse maven-metadata.xml. No need to manually parse directory names or file names.

```
http://localhost/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.foo&a=foo-bar
```

returns not only every `<version>`, but as a bonus, for every artifact of this version, all the identifiers needed to **obtain an unique download URL for any single file** residing on this Nexus instance. The identifiers required for download URL are: `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>` (both of which you say you already know), `<version>`, `<repositoryId>`, `<extension>` (and `<classifier>` which is optional and undefined in my example):

```
...
<artifact>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
  <latestSnapshot>2.8.5-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
  <latestSnapshotRepositoryId>snapshots</latestSnapshotRepositoryId>
  <latestRelease>2.8.3</latestRelease>
  <latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
  <artifactHits>
    <artifactHit>
      <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
      <artifactLinks>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>pom</extension>
        </artifactLink>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>war</extension>
        </artifactLink>
      </artifactLinks>
    </artifactHit>
  </artifactHits>
</artifact>
<artifact>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
  <latestSnapshot>2.8.5-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
  <latestSnapshotRepositoryId>snapshots</latestSnapshotRepositoryId>
  <latestRelease>2.8.3</latestRelease>
  <latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
  <artifactHits>
    <artifactHit>
      <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
      <artifactLinks>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>pom</extension>
        </artifactLink>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>war</extension>
        </artifactLink>
      </artifactLinks>
    </artifactHit>
  </artifactHits>
</artifact>
```

After you parse `lucene/search` response, a good idea would be to filter it by repositoryId being either `releases` or `snapshots`.

This answer is for Nexus 2.11.

Comment: THAT is friggin awesome! This addresses an item I have been looking to solve for a long time!

Comment: cool! it even supports * and ? as in http://localhost/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=a* (but g=* or no group at all are not supported) . see also other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958025/651288

Answer (score 5):

Usually you would want to use the lucene index maintained for the repositories for lookups like this. See [the REST documentation for the indexer plugin](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/path__lucene_search.html), you can search for groupId and artifactId here.

Answer (score 0):

I know 5 years has passed since OP but here is the url used for nexus 3 in case someone needs it: `http://nexus.domain/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=maven-snapshots&maven.groupId=com.example.pack&maven.artifactId=apo&maven.baseVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=jar`

Comment: Could you please provide a valid link, as the link provided in answer is not working.

Comment: You have to change nexus.domain for your instance of nexus. By default it should be replaced by localhost:8081 -> `http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=maven-snapshots&maven.groupId=com.example.pack&maven.artifactId=apo&maven.baseVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=jar`


Also you should replace the maven.baseVersion key.