# List of all artifacts in Nexus 2.14 repository

Tags: java, rest, maven, nexus

Can I use REST to get a list of all artifacts in a Nexus 2.14 repository?

Comment: Are you loking for something like `https://nexus:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/apache/camel/camel-core/`?

Comment: @SubOptimal No, I am not searching for a given groupId or artifactId, but I need a list of all artifacts in a given repository. The background is that I am searching for duplicate entries in different Nexus repositories of our company server.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957270/nexus-rest-api-query-artifacts-within-a-group

Answer (score 0):

An easy but not extremely fast solution is to iterate through the ´storage´ directory in Nexus. You can easily recover the GAV from the directory structure.